# Errors running Perl CGI scripts under PerlRun

Tags: perl, apache2, cgi, mod-perl

I am trying to run a Perl CGI web application under mod_perl 2.0 using PerlRun.  After making  a few simply changes to the scripts everything seems to work.

However, the Apache error_log is getting huge!  Fast.

There are many, many errors per request but they are of two types:

1)

```
Constant subroutine ModPerl::ROOT::ModPerl::PerlRun::var_www_html_myapp_main_2epl::RC_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE redefined at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/ModPerl/Util.pm line 69.
```

2)

```
Prototype mismatch: sub ModPerl::ROOT::ModPerl::PerlRun::var_www_html_myapp_main_2epl::RC_SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS: none vs () at /var/www/html/myapp/main.pl line 1054
```

This is line 1054 of main.pl:

```
use LWP::Simple qw(!head);
```

How can I get rid of these two types of errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205116/why-do-i-get-redefine-warnings-with-use-constant-under-mod-perl ?

Answer (score 3):

Both of your error messages are related to LWP::Simple.  LWP::Simple exports the HTTP constants, this causes the redefined warnings.  When you use LWP::Simple try to include only the functions that you need use LWP::Simple qw(get, getstore); You may still see the prototype mismatch errors on those functions.